# cal log , call time , call drop and traffic during a call in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone

### I have a question about the develop of an ios app

Its possible to start a call and take , call duration , traffic
 during the call , number  called , and when or if call drop?

Jailbreak its needed?

I look lots around web but i still notcsure if that its possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No the iOS SDk does not allow you this. You can get some information about calls, but not musch, with [CoreTelephony](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html).

You can get [`callID`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CTCall/callID) (which is not a phone number) and [`callState`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CTCall/callState) from [`CTCall`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html) , that is it.

Start cal you can use the `tel:` scheme.

Comment: but if i call callState i can see only the CTCallStateDialing (in case i made a phone call) that's because my app is not more in foreground. How you can take all the callStates? like CTCallStateConnected or Disconnected ?

Comment: @simas You can't, unless your app runs in the background with one of the background modes. `CTCall` was introduced for Voip clients, to check whether you can make a call. You can not write your own dialer for iOS as you can for Android.

Comment: i didn't know that is introduced for Voip client. Now it seems more clear. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes it was in one of the WWDC video, that you should check the call state in your Voip client, it could off course also be used by other apps.